# How to calculate a new variable based on pandas multidimensional dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My dataframe represents "unbalanced panel" data in long format with many periods and thousands of objects.
In the example below there is one object in several periods of time.

```
      period    object              
1 2013-01-31   object 1         
2 2013-02-28   object 1       
3 2013-04-30   object 1      
4 2013-05-31   object 1       
5 2013-06-30   object 1
```

It is needed to define a new column "enter period":

```
      period    object    enter period          
1 2013-01-31   object 1   2013-01-31      
2 2013-02-28   object 1   2013-01-31    
3 2013-04-30   object 1   2013-04-30   
4 2013-05-31   object 1   2013-04-30    
5 2013-06-30   object 1   2013-04-30
```

The logic is:

if the object is in the database without interruptions,
 then the enter period = the first period available for that object.

else - Every time when there are period gaps for the object 
enter period=first period after the gap.

In excel the formula looks like this (A-"period", B- "object", C- "enter period"):

```
C2=IF(AND(B2=B1;IFERROR(MONTH(A2)+(YEAR(A2)-2013)*12-MONTH(A1)-(YEAR(A1)-2013)*12;0)=1);C1;A2)
```

How to define such a function in python pandas and how to apply it for each object in object column?
How to refer to each object in the column? How to enter time dimension in the function?

I am new to python and any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Gaps, on a monthly level?

Comment: exactly, if there is a monthly gap.

Comment: Dear Àlex, unfortunately, the code doesn't work correctly for the whole database. For some objects it gives right result, but for the majority of objects it gives wrong result.

Comment: Okay will check at some other moment.